# Is "Forever falling to the bottom" a paradox?

Tags: paradox

Writing an English paper that requires a paradox.  Is the above a paradox?

Comment: "A [paradox](https://www.iep.utm.edu/par-log/) is generally a puzzling conclusion we seem to be driven towards by our reasoning, but which is highly counterintuitive, nevertheless." Thus, a paradox is not something false or impossible: it is something "weird" that we are forced to assert as a conclusion of some "correct" argument.

Comment: Not as you have stated it. What do you even mean? Perhaps use https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorites_paradox (also called the paradox of the heap)

Comment: How's that different from saying: I'm gonna walk around forever ? So no...

Comment: It is more of an oxymoron, see [Difference between Paradox and Oxymoron](http://www.differencebetween.info/difference-between-paradox-and-oxymoron), and questions about definitions of terms are better suited for English SE.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like Zeno's paradox: to fall to the bottom of a well, first you need to get to the halfway point before you're all the way down, and even if you reach that, you first need to get to the point half-way between that point and the very bottom before you can get all the way to the bottom, etc. etc. And so it looks like you can never get to the very bottom.

Comment: I even find Zeno is logically contradictory.

Comment: @Explorer_N What exactly do mean? What exactly is logically contradictory?

Answer (score 2):

> Is “Forever falling to the bottom” a paradox?

If someone is falling to the bottom and will do so forever, then, in reality, there is no bottom. Or if someone is falling and will do so forever, then, actually, they are not falling; they are better described as suspended in space.

So the phrase is saying that a certain situation is and is not at the same time.